# My Retina MacBook Pro just had a kernel panic while browsing, what caused it to crash?

Tags: osx-lion, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I just got a Retina MacBook Pro and this is my second day of using it.

I was just browsing the internet and a message popped up saying

> Your computer was restarted because of a problem

… along with some other text. Here is the output from the panic log:

```
Fri Jul 20 22:11:00 2012
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f823e8b9c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff81a1a9b990, CR3: 0x000000002d616039, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000004242, RBX: 0x0000000000000077, RCX: 0xffffff81a1a8b000, RDX: 0x0000000000795bf2
RSP: 0xffffff81e71cb9b0, RBP: 0xffffff81e71cb9c0, RSI: 0xffffff8028114000, RDI: 0xffffff802aa22000
R8:  0x0000000000000075, R9:  0xffffff7f82442360, R10: 0xffffff81e71cb92c, R11: 0xffffff81e71cb930
R12: 0xffffff8024e67488, R13: 0xffffff802aa22000, R14: 0xffffff81a1a8b000, R15: 0xffffff802aa22000
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f823e8b9c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0xffffff81a1a9b990, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81e71cb660 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff81e71cb6e0 : 0xffffff80002c4794 
0xffffff81e71cb890 : 0xffffff80002da55d 
0xffffff81e71cb8b0 : 0xffffff7f823e8b9c 
0xffffff81e71cb9c0 : 0xffffff7f823ed0a5 
0xffffff81e71cbb00 : 0xffffff7f823ea010 
0xffffff81e71cbb60 : 0xffffff800065551e 
0xffffff81e71cbb80 : 0xffffff8000655dfa 
0xffffff81e71cbbe0 : 0xffffff800065659b 
0xffffff81e71cbd20 : 0xffffff80002a3f08 
0xffffff81e71cbe20 : 0xffffff8000223096 
0xffffff81e71cbe50 : 0xffffff80002148a9 
0xffffff81e71cbeb0 : 0xffffff800021bbd8 
0xffffff81e71cbf10 : 0xffffff80002af140 
0xffffff81e71cbfb0 : 0xffffff80002dab5e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(7.2.4)[097ADF6F-75A9-30B9-99DA-BC8368951241]@0xffffff7f823e0000->0xffffff7f82446fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[4B5D32E9-6FDC-351F-9E42-24BED523464D]@0xffffff7f80829000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[45D98485-3AEE-3A4E-8FDC-AA86CE0A2F79]@0xffffff7f8088d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[EF881EFF-DB09-3850-B84C-B9A7CA254BB2]@0xffffff7f80854000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
11E2068

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.1: Wed May  2 19:34:43 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.28.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: My Magical UUID
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 23730041049309
last loaded kext at 300487456992: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.1.19 (addr 0xffffff7f8176c000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.19
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 9.8.1
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   6.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.5d3
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.2.3fc5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.3fc5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.3fc5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.6f7
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.32
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.1.32
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.GeForce   7.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   7.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 7.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.6f7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   551.7.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.3b7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.3fc5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc17
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.3fc5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.3fc5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.32
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    7.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.nvGK100hal 7.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.nvGF100hal 7.2.4
com.apple.NVDAResman    7.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.6f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.6f7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  13
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.5.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.5
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your crash is related to the `AppleIntelHD4000Graphics` kernel extensions. It wouldn't be the first time Chrome caused troubles with that particular chipset: [Google confirms Chrome bug is causing crashes on latest MacBook Air](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/06/google-confirms-chrome-bug-is-causing-crashes-on-latest-macbook-air/):

> The problem seems to have first been discovered early last week, according to reports in Apple's [support discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4034535). The common thread among users experiencing crashes was the use of Chrome, which seemed to cause a kernel panic related to the drivers for Intel's HD4000 integrated graphics.
>
> Google says it has filed a bug report with Apple concerning the driver issue, "since it should not be possible for an application to trigger such behavior," the company told Gizmodo. Chrome developers continue to work on a fix for the resource leak, but in the interim, Google has pushed out an update to Chrome that disables GPU acceleration on Macs with HD4000 graphics until the issue is resolved.

So, unless you haven't done so yet, update Chrome to the newest version. Try using another browser in the meantime and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have a retina macbook pro so in order to use a browser at the correct resolution I have to use chrome canary, apparently that doesn't have GPU acceleration disabled

Comment: I would probably get involved in the Chrome canary bug tracker discussions regarding that subject!